# Check/Uncheck the checkbox with same checkbox in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have the html like below

```
    <script>
          $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.select_unselect_all').click(function(){
                   console.log('hurray>>>');
                    $('.se_unse').prop('checked', true);

            }); 
          });  
    </script>


<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="stdtable">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th><input id="" class="select_unselect_all" type="checkbox"/></th>
         <th>product name</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    {% for val in values %}
      <tr>
         <td><input id="" class="se_unse" type="checkbox" /></td>
         <td>{{val.name}}</td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
   </tbody>
</table>
```

So from the above html and jquery code, when we click on checkbox with class `select_unselect_all`, all the remaining checkboxes in `tbody` block with class `se_unse` should be selected(Its working ind with the above jquery code).

So when we again click on the same checkbox with class `select_unselect_all` in `thead` section all the checked checkboxed should be unchecked

So how to implement this in my above code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.select_unselect_all').change(function () {
        $('.se_unse').prop('checked', this.checked);
    });
});
```

`this.checked` tells if the checkbox is checked or not. Return Boolean value.

[.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
  $('.select_unselect_all').click(function(){
      $('.se_unse').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
  });
});
```